# Return errors in server side validation with Laravel and Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to return the errors in server side validation so the user can know which error they have, but I don't know how to return something that it is understandable for a normal person.

Here's my front-end

```
<v-form>
    <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6">
            <v-text-field label="Serial Number" v-model="plane.serial_number" color="black" counter="30"></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>

    <v-btn color="yellow" class="black-text" @click="add()">Submit</v-btn>

</v-form>

<script>
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            errors: [],
            plane: {
                serial_number: '',
            },
        }
    },


    methods: {
        add() {
            const params = {
                serial_number: this.plane.serial_number,
            };

            axios.post(`/planes`, params)
                .then(res => {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Success!',
                        html: 'Plane created successfully!',
                        icon: 'success',
                        confirmButtonText: 'OK',
                    })
                }).catch(e => {
                    this.errors = e;
                    console.log(this.errors);
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Error!',
                        icon: 'error',
                    })
                })
        },

         }

}
</script>
```

Back-end

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'serial_number' => ['required','string', 'unique:airplanes']
        ]);

        $airplane = new Airplane();
        $airplane->serial_number = $request->serial_number;
        $airplane->save();
    }
```

The console.log isn't returning anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `this.errors` if you output `this.errors.message` you *should* see a friendly message. Hope that helps! ... You can also dig into the `this.errors.response` object which has things like the headers and status.